# Remove SQL constraint in OpenERP7

Tags: openerp-7

In OpenERP7, the core module `account` has a declaration for `account.invoice` which has, at some point, the following declaration:

addons/account/account_invoice.py:343

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('number_uniq', 'unique(number, company_id, journal_id, type)', 'Invoice Number must be unique per Company!'),
]
```

In a module which redefined `account.invoice` I wanted to remove the constraint with two different approaches:

1. Removing it in **init** (account_invoice::init(self, pool, cr))

   ```
   def __init__(self, pool, cr):
       super(account_invoice, self).__init__(pool, cr)
       try:
           cr.execute('ALTER TABLE account_invoice DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS account_invoice_number_uniq')
       finally:
           pass
   ```
2. Replacing the constraint

   ```
   _sql_constraints = [
       ('number_uniq', 'check(1=1)', 'Dummy check, always true, used to replace the previous constraint'),
   ]
   ```

However, when I reinstall the module in which those two declarations were made, I get an error (in the PG logs) telling me that the constraint `account_invoice_number_uniq` could not be craeted for a unique key since there's repeated data.

How can I prevent having such error? How can I prevent the system attempting to create (first; then... replace/delete) the constraint?

Comment: Just try with your inherited file replace your constraint with same constraint name with different parameter

Comment: check it with field as well as add your updated constraint in your py file and try the same think again

Comment: Hello Luis Massuelli,

Here, you can drop constraint directly from database, If you have access of that database then you can directly drop it by following query.

ALTER TABLE account_invoice DROP CONSTRAINT account_invoice_number_uniq;

Answer (score 0):

Check the Below Reference Link to remove the SQL Constraint Of Parent Class in Odoo

[Click To See the Reference For Remove the SQL Constraint In Odoo(formally OpenERP)](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/changing-sql-constraints-child-models-odoo-8.html)

Comment: This example clearly explains it is intended for Odoo (and not OpenERP 7).

Comment: okey good and you can easily convert your odoo to OpenERP 7.0 and check it with OpenERP 7.0 i hope that should helpful